# Incomplete Data from json_decode

Tags: php, json

Okay some basic info...

PHP 5.3.5
JSON 1.2.1

This is all running on a local XAMPP server. Basically, my code below is returning an incomplete associative array.  The json_last_error() returns 0.  I have searched the net but could not find this type of error without haveing a specific json error returned.

```
<?php
$ShippingObj = json_decode($_POST['formData'], true);
echo json_last_error();
echo $ShippingObj;
```

I have validated the string with JSONLint..and here is what its output was....

```
array (
      'name' => 'newShipment',
      'comments' => '',
      'count' => 1,
      'itemID' => 0,
      'itemWeight' => 7.548,
      'itemLength' => 0,
      'itemWidth' => 0,
      'itemHeight' => 0,
      'limits' => '',
      'collection' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'name' => '8x6x4 Standard',
          'comments' => '',
          'count' => 5,
          'itemID' => '3',
          'itemWeight' => 7.5475,
          'itemLength' => '8',
          'itemWidth' => '6',
          'itemHeight' => '4',
          'limits' => 'MFR',
          'collection' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'ID' => '1',
              'Name' => ' TA-200 Demarcation Enclosure',
              'Qty' => 1,
              'Weight' => '0.34',
            ),
            1 => 
            array (
              'ID' => '2',
              'Name' => ' CG-1000 Demarcation Enclosure',
              'Qty' => 4,
              'Weight' => '1',
            ),
            2 => 
            array (
              'ID' => '19',
              'Name' => ' FM-02 Stereo FM Transmitter',
              'Qty' => 1,
              'Weight' => '0.1625',
            ),
            3 => 
            array (
              'ID' => '20',
              'Name' => ' Renard 64 Rev XC Parts Kit w/PCB',
              'Qty' => 1,
              'Weight' => '1.125',
            ),
            4 => 
            array (
              'ID' => '21',
              'Name' => ' SSRez Parts Kit w/PCB - Set of 8',
              'Qty' => 2,
              'Weight' => '0.86',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Which is a valid JSON construct.....here is the input that I copied into http://www.functions-online.com/json_decode.html to verify my string.

```
$returnValue = json_decode('{"name":"newShipment","comments":"","count":1,"itemID":0,"itemWeight":7.548,"itemLength":0,"itemWidth":0,"itemHeight":0,"limits":"","collection":{"0":{"name":"8x6x4 Standard","comments":"","count":5,"itemID":"3","itemWeight":7.5475,"itemLength":"8","itemWidth":"6","itemHeight":"4","limits":"MFR","collection":{"0":{"ID":"1","Name":" TA-200 Demarcation Enclosure","Qty":1,"Weight":"0.34"},"1":{"ID":"2","Name":" CG-1000 Demarcation Enclosure","Qty":4,"Weight":"1"},"2":{"ID":"19","Name":" FM-02 Stereo FM Transmitter","Qty":1,"Weight":"0.1625"},"3":{"ID":"20","Name":" Renard 64 Rev XC Parts Kit w/PCB","Qty":1,"Weight":"1.125"},"4":{"ID":"21","Name":" SSRez Parts Kit w/PCB - Set of 8","Qty":2,"Weight":"0.86"}}}}}', true);
```

The first section of code returns the below for $ShippingObj.  Note the "[collection] => array(5) " that does not expand out...its empty.  I have checked the string from the previous JS and it is fine.

```
array(10) (
  [name] => (string) newShipment
  [comments] => (string)
  [count] => (int) 1
  [itemID] => (int) 0
  [itemWeight] => (float) 16.2955
  [itemLength] => (int) 0
  [itemWidth] => (int) 0
  [itemHeight] => (int) 0
  [limits] => (string)
  [collection] => array(1) (
    [0] => array(10) (
      [name] => (string) CG2000 OEM Box
      [comments] => (string)
      [count] => (int) 5
      [itemID] => (string) 2
      [itemWeight] => (float) 8.1475
      [itemLength] => (string) 21
      [itemWidth] => (string) 16.5
      [itemHeight] => (string) 12.5
      [limits] => (string) 2ND
      [collection] => array(5) (
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Just a guess (doubt it will work), try doing `json_decode(..., true, 512)`

Comment: hmmm lol tried that several hours ago..including 6, 128, and so on.  I have put some things in there that no coder in his/her right mind would do.  I am losing what grey hair I have left.

Comment: Where is 'CG2000 OEM Box' comming from? It's not part of the JSON string as printed above.

Comment: If it says array(5) () and there is nothing in it looks like a problem with var_dump(). Maybe you limited the nesting depth - e.g. xdebug can do that.

Comment: I am using xdebug.  Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Arnold...this is not static data and I ran it from two different runs.  The problem is consistant even thought some of the data is not.

Comment: Try `ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', -1);`

Comment: ah!  I am looking for my php.ini file settings now.  I not not specifically using var_dump...I use Netbeans as a UI and copied the data from that interface.

Comment: this is quite bizzare....this is about Netbeans.  I had a watch on $ShippingObj and it shows only the levels above.  However, that window already had ShippingObj (without the php $) and it had everything in it.  It appears that this is an internal something in how Netbeans does watches.......

Comment: what gets to me is that I have been chasing a NON-Issue for 6 hours!!! ugh!  Well at least is not my coding ROFLMAO!

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping out....all the questions were useful and lead to the correct answer.  First off I was trusting the NetBeans interface to avoid using multiple var_dumps.  Had I just done this at first, I would have answered my own question really fast.